# Using Azure Computer Vision API with mathematical expressions

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-cognitive-services

i'm kind of new to the Azure Computer Vision API but i'm interested to use this for parsing a lot of mathematical documents.

I wanted to use [mxParser](http://mathparser.org/) for evaluating the output string from the Vision API but currently only text recocgnition is supported.
Does somebody know if the API is usable for this kind of scenario in any way (or will be in the future)?

If this is not a good use-case for  this kind of AI API what would you recommend to use for generating a usable string expression from handwritten mathematical documents ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the PM reponsible for CV API. Currently, we don't support mathematical expressions and there is no plan to support in the near term (6 months).  However, it is an interesting scenario and something to consider in the future.  Thank you for the suggestion and keep the feedback coming :)!

Comment: Thanks @cthrash :) seems like a good solution for me now. Still interested in the Azure version tho.

Comment: Also Thanks for answering my question so fast @julia-nik  :)